# how to close a specific dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**I want to close a specified dialog.**

My case:

- Open 2 dialogs (1) and (2), and 2 dialogs are showing at the same time. (2) is overriding (1) and I want to close (1) first.

With Android: I can assign each dialog to a variable and use `dialog.dismiss()`.

I came across this example, it works but it doesn't seem to be the best way.
[How to close a specific Flutter AlertDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262042/how-to-close-a-specific-flutter-alertdialog)

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do that with Dialog because Dialog use Navigator, which use Stack only allow you to push and pop the top Route

Another option you can use to implement this is `OverLayEntry`, like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry1;
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _overlayEntry1 = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    _overlayEntry2 = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _overlayEntry1?.remove();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_overlayEntry1!);
            Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_overlayEntry2!);
          },
          child: Text('Show overlay'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right and your code work right. But I hope there is another answer . OverlayEntry is already mentioned in the example above. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can close the first dialogue before the second dialogue pops up by using `Navigator.pop(context)` or if you use GetX then you can use `Get.back()` before calling the second dialogue opening function.

If you want the first dialogue opens up after the second dialogue pops then you can try this:

When you close the second dialogue you will call the first dialogue up by using `.then((e)=> 'previous dialogue open function goes here')`.

So at the same time, no two dialogues are opened. Just use them one by one.

Comment: Oh. I don't want to close the previous popup and then turn it back on because there will be an effect of turning the popup on and off and in my case, the number of popups that appear is not fixed. I need a method that can close exactly the specified popup. Thank you for your answer!